# ssplit.eolonly with Chinese text

Tags: stanford-nlp

I am trying to parse a raw Chinese text file (one line per sentence) with the Stanford NN Dependency Parser.

For English text I was able to use the 'ssplit' annotator with the 'ssplit.eolonly' option in order to split the document into sentences, however this option seems to fail for Chinese. Parsing works for an input file with a single line, however if there are multiple lines they are treated as a single sentence.

Is there a simple solution to get 'ssplit.eolonly' to work with Chinese? The command I ran was as follows:

```
java edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP \
-annotators segment,ssplit,pos,depparse \
-customAnnotatorClass.segment edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.ChineseSegmenterAnnotator \
-segment.model edu/stanford/nlp/models/segmenter/chinese/ctb.gz \
-segment.sighanCorporaDict edu/stanford/nlp/models/segmenter/chinese \
-segment.serDictionary edu/stanford/nlp/models/segmenter/chinese/dict-chris6.ser.gz \
-segment.sighanPostProcessing true \
-ssplit.eolonly \
-pos.model edu/stanford/nlp/models/pos-tagger/chinese-distsim/chinese-distsim.tagger \
-depparse.model edu/stanford/nlp/models/parser/nndep/CTB_CoNLL_params.txt.gz \
-depparse.language Chinese \
-file in -outputDirectory out
```

Comment: Hi John—we're looking into this.. may be a bug within the segmenter. We'll keep you posted. Thanks for asking!

Comment: Hi Jon, thanks for looking into this! It seems like maybe the segmenter is somehow losing the '\n' tokens?

Comment: Hi - have you any updates on this issue?

Comment: John, sorry for the delay—the research group has been distracted by the deadline for a big academic conference this Friday. We will be able to spare some cycles for this soon..
Of course, this is an open-source project—if you are feeling motivated you can try to patch this problem on your own :)

Comment: No problem, it's not so urgent - good luck with ACL!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, not at the moment (Apr 2015). The current segmenter doesn't support preserving line information. This would be a good thing to fix at some point....